# Simple Payment Form with Worldpay

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, plugin-sproutforms, plugin-freeform, plugin-guestentries, plugin-amforms

Currently looking into a site which requires a simple invoice payment form which needs to checkout with Worldpay.
Forms fields are simply Name, Email, Address, Invoice No and Invoice Amount.
I would like the payments to be stored in the backend of the CMS - and whether successful or not.

What is the most straight forward way to achieve this?

Current Thoughts:

1 - Craft Commerce - Will I need this full solution? Can it accept custom price fields - as per Invoice Amount?

2 - Create Basic Form which can save the entries using the Guest Entries Plugin - When submitted it saves the details and loads a page on my site to verify information which also loads the details into the basic Worldpay Form method with a Complete Payment button.
Then to update record if payment successful - enter a url in the Worldpay Callback url which calls a custom plugin which will update the Payment Status of the entry. (I haven't created any plugins yet but in theory this one should be straight forward?)

3 - Use some of the existing form solutions out there and hook into some events with those to update payment status? Sprout Forms, Freeform, Form Builder, AM Forms-